# Odd update behavior when updating while using a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

This is kind of a followup to my question [Reference a column and update it in the same statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458395/reference-a-column-and-update-it-in-the-same-statement). I am now trying to use a local variable and have it updated in the same update statement.

```
declare @tmp table (ID int primary key, UNPAID money)

insert into @tmp select 1, 31.63
insert into @tmp select 2, 49.20
insert into @tmp select 3, 99.00
insert into @tmp select 4, 41.00

declare @paymentAmmount money
select @paymentAmmount = SUM(UNPAID) from @tmp
            
declare cur_oustandingAR cursor local static for select ID  from @tmp order by ID
open cur_oustandingAR

declare @currentID int

fetch next from cur_oustandingAR into @currentID
while (@@fetch_status = 0 and @paymentAmmount > 0)
begin
    begin
        update @tmp
            set UNPAID = case when @paymentAmmount > UNPAID then 0 else UNPAID - @paymentAmmount end,
                @paymentAmmount = case when @paymentAmmount > UNPAID then @paymentAmmount - UNPAID else 0 end
            where ID = @currentID
    end
    fetch next from cur_oustandingAR into @currentID
end

select * from @tmp
select @paymentAmmount as LeftoverPayment
```

You can run the query [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/86502/query-for-se-question#resultSets), here is the results it gives

```
ID          UNPAID
----------- ---------------------
1           0.00
2           0.00
3           58.00
4           41.00

LeftoverPayment 
--------------- 
0
```

All of the value should of been 0 and `@paymentAmmount` at the end should also be 0. What is going wrong that is causing the values to not be applied correctly?

---

P.S. I know how to [fix it](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/86499/query-for-se-question-working-version), just break the one query in to the 3 following queries, but I wanted to do it as a single query so I did not need as many lookups against the real table

```
select @oldUnpaid = UNPAID from @tmp where ID = @currentID
update @tmp 
    set UNPAID = case when @paymentAmmount > UNPAID then 0 else UNPAID - @paymentAmmount end
    where ID = @currentID
select @paymentAmmount = case when @paymentAmmount > @oldUnpaid then @paymentAmmount - @oldUnpaid else 0 end
```

I just wanted to know why what I am doing currently does not work.

Comment: why use a cursor? (which is missing the close and deallocate, btw)

Comment: @MitchWheat 1) cursors declared local do not need to be closed/deallocated :P 2) this is a simplified re-creation of a much larger query. I need to reconcile payments applying the payment to the oldest charge first.

Comment: "cursors declared local do not need to be closed/deallocated" - do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @MitchWheat The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx)  *"The cursor is implicitly deallocated when the batch, stored procedure, or trigger terminates, unless the cursor was passed back in an OUTPUT parameter. If it is passed back in an OUTPUT parameter, the cursor is deallocated when the last variable referencing it is deallocated or goes out of scope."*

Comment: "You don't explicitly have to" ~= "You shouldn't." I always close and deallocate my cursors, particularly if they're part of a larger procedure. Why let them persist beyond the point where you no longer need them?

Comment: @AaronBertrand as do I, but for quick striped down sample code, it's not really necessary. And I will say the "real" version of this does close and deallocate even though it is declared local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @tmp table (ID int primary key, UNPAID money)

insert into @tmp select 1, 31.63
insert into @tmp select 2, 49.20
insert into @tmp select 3, 99.00
insert into @tmp select 4, 41.00

declare @paymentAmmount money
declare @paymentAmmountbuf money
select @paymentAmmount = SUM(UNPAID) from @tmp
declare cur_oustandingAR cursor local static for select ID  from @tmp order by ID
open cur_oustandingAR

declare @currentID int

fetch next from cur_oustandingAR into @currentID
while (@@fetch_status = 0 and @paymentAmmount > 0)
begin
    begin
        select @paymentAmmountbuf=@paymentAmmount

        update @tmp
            set UNPAID = case when @paymentAmmountbuf > UNPAID then 0 else UNPAID - @paymentAmmountbuf end,
                @paymentAmmount = case when @paymentAmmount > UNPAID then @paymentAmmount - UNPAID else 0 end
            where ID = @currentID
    end
    fetch next from cur_oustandingAR into @currentID
end

select * from @tmp
select @paymentAmmount as LeftoverPayment
```

Comment: Sneaky! I think this may end up being my solution but I will wait a bit to see if any other answers come along.